# TargetInvocationException on repeater

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a simple Repeater Bound to a List of Objects, the object containing a series of strings for rendering.

The object is the following:

```
class BestPractice
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

rendered using the following code to make sure the loop wasn't causing problems:

```
List<BestPractice> BestPractices = new List<BestPractice>();
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    BestPractice bp = new BestPractice();
                    bp.Author = "test";//(string)item["Author"];
                    bp.Body = "test";// (string)item["Body"];
                    bp.Title = "test";// (string)item["Title"];
                    BestPractices.Add(bp);
                }

                BPRepeater.DataSource = BestPractices;
                BPRepeater.DataBind();
```

I've stepped through the code to make sure the List contained an item, and that that item had populated strings before being databound. The Exception happens here in the .g.cs file:

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public void @__DataBind__control4(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem Container;
            System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl target;
            target = ((System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl)(sender));
            Container = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem)(target.BindingContainer));
            target.SetDataBoundString(0, System.Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Author"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        }
```

The following is the exception itself:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Property accessor 'Author' on object 'Carpool_Webparts.Offer_Details.BestPractice' threw the following exception:'Carpool_Webparts.Offer_Details.BestPractice.get_Author()'
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
       at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
       at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)
       at Carpool_Webparts.Offer_Details.Offer_Details.__DataBind__control4(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
  InnerException: System.MethodAccessException
       Message=Carpool_Webparts.Offer_Details.BestPractice.get_Author()
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandle method, IntPtr parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
       InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
            Message=Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
                 at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException)
                 at System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh)
                 at System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh)
                 at System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet)
                 at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack securityContext)
                 at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant)
            InnerException:
```

I am totally lost :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% certain what the specific issue is, but based on the error message, I would suggest two possible changes:

1) Verify that the BestPractice class is public (you can ratchet the exposure level back down once you verify it is or isn't working).

2) Change the auto-implemented properties to member-backed properties. The inner exception indicates there is a security exception on the get_Author accessor, which leads me to believe that the auto-implementation could have something to do with it.

Comment: The class was not public, but was in the same namespace as the loop, so the loop ran without issues. It seems as though the databind() code, though fired in the correct namespace actually executes in another, and unless the class is public, databind() cannot access it. This seems like something that would be nice to catch at compile time, but I understand why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the most fresh version of the assembly is visible to SharePoint. The most reliable way to achieve that is to ensure that the dll is NOT in the web app bin folder (remove it from there if it is there) and copy the latest built version to GAC. If the error is gone - ajust your deployment process respectively.